# How can I prevent LinkedIn from showing my name to others in their feed as a group/brand's without having to unfollow it?

Tags: linkedin

How can I prevent LinkedIn from showing my name to others in their feed as a group/brand's without having to unfollow it?

[image]

I don't want my name to show up as part of such promoted post, and any other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/meet-the-team: Switch  `Representing your organization and interests` to no.

[image]